# error when calling the GETTERMSETS method using the taxonomyclientservice

Tags: web-services, error, taxonomy, soap

do you have any idea about this type of exception "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

I have receveided this exception when I tried to call the method "GetTermsets" using the web service "taxonomyclientservice.asmx"

Here is the portion of my code:

```
Dim ts As New TaxonomyService.Taxonomywebservice
    ts.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    ts.Url = SiteUrl + "/_vti_bin/taxonomyclientservice.asmx"
    Dim timestamp As String
    timestamp = String.Empty

    Try

        termsetXML = ts.GetTermSets(sspId, termSetId, 1033, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks.ToString, 0, timestamp)
        Console.WriteLine("This is the XMLstring that contain all the temrs of the term set : {0}", termsetXML)

        Return termsetXML
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
```

The values of sspId and termSetId are of String type and they get values from an other method that I tested and it is working so well.

Unfortunatally, there no programmer in my team to help in such situationI

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have probably found the solution by now, but just in case someone else has the same problem: You should include the tags with the parameters you send to the `taxonomywebservice.GetTermSets` function.

So, just add your own values for [YourTermStoreId] and [YourTermSetId] and it should do the job.

Here's a code sample:

```
Dim oldtimestamp As String = "<timeStamp>633992461437070000</timeStamp>"
Dim clientVersion As String = "<version>3</version>"
Dim termStoreIds As String = "<termStoreId>" & [YourTermStoreId] & "</termStoreId>"
Dim termSetIds As String = "<termSetId>" & [YourTermSetId] & "</termSetId>"
Dim timeStamp As String = Nothing

termsetXML = ts.GetTermSets(
                            termStoreIds,
                            termSetIds,
                            lcId,
                            oldtimestamp,
                            clientVersion,
                            timeStamp
                           )
```

Comment: The solution is I should wrap every parameter in my function with XML